# Laravel Check Value For One Specific Record In hasMany Relationship Within Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to add some conditional logic to my query builder but am struggling to find the right function I need to be looking in to...

Take this example;
We have model A which has many model Bs. `Model B` contains `name` and `value` columns. I now want to return all model As which have a model B with name 'score' and `value > 50`, AND another model B which has name 'group' and value 'debug'.

Without resorting to basic `PHP` once the models have all been returned, how would I filter by specific hasMany relationships within the query builder?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Eloquent:**

Relationship: in model `A`:

```php
public function b()
{
   return $this->hasMany(B::class);
}
```

```php
A::whereHas('b', function($b) {
   $b->where(function($query) {
       $query->whereName('score')
             ->where('value', '>', 50);
       })
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->whereName('group')
              ->where('value', 'debug');
     });
  })->get();
```

**Using query builder:**

```php
\DB::table('a')->join('b', function ($join) {
            $join->on('a.id', '=', 'b.a_id');
        })->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('b.name', 'score')
                ->where('b.value', '>', 50);
        })->orWhere(function ($q) {
            $q->where('b.name', 'group')
                ->where('b.value', 'debug');
        })
        ->get();
```